# Trying to build custom profile for Firejail, need some help.

Tags: tor

I've been trying to learn how to sandbox applications with Firejail. However the application I wish to sandbox, Tor Browser, does not have a default profile. So from what I've been reading I need to create a custom profile however I don't know how. I've been trying to understand this https://firejail.wordpress.com/documentation-2/building-custom-profiles/ but these instructions already assume the user has extensive knowledge with Linux already. I do not know how to create directories from a command line so they lost me at step 2. Step 3 also seems to be very vague and dosen't go into detail on how to accomplish this.

Comment: You can find 3 profiles for Tor here: https://github.com/chiraag-nataraj/firejail-profiles   So it might be simpler for now for you to use them or at least to start from them instead of from scratch.

Comment: Thanks, so what do I do just copy and paste in terminal?

Comment: Download one, put it as `tor.profile` under your `.config/firejail`  directory and then run the application with `firejail tor`.

Comment: Thank you. I don't see a download option though. It only says "Find file" and "Copy path".

Comment: Note that we are going offtopic for both your specific question and this website. I would gently recommend you try to make yourself more familiar with the linux shell, by reading some tutorial (and never operate as root) as it will make your life far simpler. As for the download and only as example: `cd ~/.config/firejail ; wget -O tor.profile https://raw.githubusercontent.com/chiraag-nataraj/firejail-profiles/master/tor.profile`   (see the "Raw" button on top right)

Comment: Okay I clicked on the RAW button but it just opened the same code up in a isolated window.  What do I do next?

Comment: Paste the command I gave you in a terminal.

Comment: Okay. Expanding on that topic do you have any specific Linux shell tutorials in mind that might be of use? Or should I just check out youtube videos?

Comment: I did the terminal command you gave and it worked. However it still wouldn't open tor when I tried to run the command "firejail tor".

Comment: No specific example in mind. I wouldn't recommend videos except if you understand/remember things more by hearing than reading (but it makes referencing, copy/pasting, etc... so much more difficult). See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A_Quick_Introduction_to_Unix for an introduction for example.

Comment: It keeps coming back to "Error: cannot open profile file /etc/firejail/tor.local"

Comment: Yeah it's not working. Any other ideas?